# UrlFetchApp.fetch returns "Timeout" after 1min

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-api

I got a timeout error after 1 min. from the below code.
Can I set a timeout value?

```
function apiPost(token, url, body) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    method: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': token
    },
    payload: JSON.stringify(body)
  });
  return JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
}
```

Comment: Try `'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token`

Comment: @ra89fi there are more authorization schemes than just bearer token.

Comment: @tehhowch What other types of auth tokens are used with header 'Authorization' ?

Comment: @ra89fi https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization#Directives